# Ubuntu 23.10, no VirtualBox available. What can be done?

Tags: virtualbox, 23.10

VirtualBox is key for me right now as I want to have Cursor IDE in a Windows VM because the Linux AppImage doesn't work.

Also for some of my security learning running Kali and my VM's from school.

What is a workaround?

Edit: Virtualbox 7.0 available with `(base) nyck33@nyck33-tt:~$ sudo apt install virtualbox`

but the tunneler for OpenZiti does not work on 23.10 so I'm starting to wonder if this was a bad idea.

A developer offered a workaround on the OpenZiti forum to use the Jammy version but I heard that could cause problems for the OS.

What are workarounds when I come into this situation again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what is an acceptable "workaround" for you, the answer differs.

### Workaround 1: Use QEMU/KVM stack with Virt-manager as GUI

Assuming you don't care about the application used for virtualization and you only care about the end result (Windows VM with your required application running within), I suggest trying to use the QEMU/KVM stack with virt-manager user interface.

Check if your device supports KVM acceleration:

```
kvm-ok
```

You should get:

```
INFO: /dev/kvm exists
KVM acceleration can be used
```

Install the necessary packages for QEMU/KVM stack:

```
sudo apt install qemu qemu-kvm libvirt-daemon libvirt-daemon-system libvirt-clients bridge-utils
```

Now, install the virt-manager frontend:

```
sudo apt install virt-manager
```

Now, you can just add the new VM using the GUI and go from there:
[image: virt-manager GUI]

KVM should give you near-native performance, so you should not see any performance decrease compared to VirtualBox.

### Workaround 2: Build VirtualBox from source

I personally **would not do this** unless I absolutely must do so, but if you HAVE TO use VirtualBox (for example, you have a specific premade VM image that you have to use that is in exclusive VirtualBox format), then [you can try building it according to their build instructions](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Build_instructions). I would strongly suggest to go with QEMU/KVM stack if you don't have to use a specific pre-made VM though, it would take considerably less effort and is more likely to work immediately.

Comment: Does 3d accel work with KVM?

Comment: @Denis Are you asking about 3D acceleration without GPU passthrough?

You can perform a full GPU passthrough while using QEMU/KVM stack, which is how I run my Windows VM. Performance-wise I didn't see much difference from the days I used to run Windows on bare metal, but I did not run any thorough tests so your mileage may vary.

As for the **GPU acceleration without passthrough**, I have never attempted this. According to this [GitHub GIST, link to web archive just in case,](http://web.archive.org/web/20230219172916/https://gist.github.com/plembo/bdaa6278d515a4edfb03e33b5b9177be) 1/2

Comment: you can achieve this with VirGL, and according to [this AU question](http://web.archive.org/web/20231023155019/https://superuser.com/questions/1804067/how-do-i-get-a-multi-display-virgl-3d-accelerated-qemu-vm-on-a-nvidia-card-in-vi) there's anecdotal evidence that it works for at least one monitor. 2/2

Comment: thanks for the reply! Whatever works. I do have Amd iGPU tho I was having some issues with it when I first tried/booted my new system. Ubuntu 23.10 desktop looked fine but applications where white/garbled. Also performance wise I wonder it pass through with iGPU would be better, or a virtual GPU using dedicated nvidia...